# VSCode with Anaconda finds module in Run in Terminal but not in Run code or debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, vscode-debugger

I have a really simple problem that I can't solve: when I run any python code in Integrated Terminal with vscode I can use my virtual environment created on Anaconda, but when I try to debug or use the button "run code" he clearly doesn't use my actual environment (and by that, don't finding my modules).

My Settings Json:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Giovani\\anaconda3\\python.exe",
"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
"python.jediEnabled": false,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
"editor.tabSize": 4 }
```

And Lauch.json:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
] }
```

Images showing the issue: 
 Running without a problem in the integrated terminal:
[Running in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSS38.png)

Running in "run code" or debugging:[Run Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzmBA.png)

Objective: Use the same virtual environment as in "python.pythonPath" on the debugger or the "run code" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try launching VS Code from your activated conda environment. Then from within VS Code select the environment you activated by running the `Python: Select Interpreter` command.